# SR latch timing diagram or waveform with delay, help!

Tags: flipflop, latch, waveform, diagram, timing-analysis

I'm having trouble solving these two problems (my solution and general solution showed):
[image]

[image]

What I did was follow the truth table and based on the combination on the graph draw the appropriate state with a delay of 10ns:
[image]

PLEASE HELP ME UNDERSTAND HOW TO DO IT AND WHERE I'VE GONE WRONG AS IM STRUGGLING TO DO THIS.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do know what an SR latch looks like right ? https://www.google.ca/imgres?imgurl=https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/04173.png&imgrefurl=https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-10/s-r-latch/&h=168&w=463&tbnid=sedH7-_0ygTS-M:&tbnh=76&tbnw=210&usg=__1VNOLEliQ2BZb6lR8VJ7SZ7PygU%3D&vet=10ahUKEwiruJuUmb_YAhVG_4MKHekwBdcQ9QEIKzAA..i&docid=tAfz8ArDBIpIvM&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiruJuUmb_YAhVG_4MKHekwBdcQ9QEIKzAA

Comment: Yes. What do I deduce from that then?

Comment: How many gate delays from the set pin to the Q pin? and from the reset pin to the Q/ pin?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Note the path from Set to Q/ is only one gate delay, but from Set to Q is two gate delays. That is, when Set goes high, Q/ goes low one gate delay (10nS)later, which causes Q to go high one gate delay after that, for a total of 20nS.

Similarly, the path from Reset to Q is only one gate delay, but from Reset to Q/ is two gate delays.

You need to factor in those different delays into your timing diagram.

Comment: I get your point but I'm unable to visualize both in my mind and and paper how it would look.

Comment: @LucaS 
 
 
Look at the first example in your question. Note Set goes high, and then Q/ changes to low 10nS later, then Q changes to high 10nS after that. That difference is because of the extra gate delay.

Comment: So I've done the first example again from scratch as you said and it worked. I'll now do the second and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I just have one question if I was in an exam condition, without solutions, I would look at the graphs to find the initial values of set and reset however to find the initial values of Q and Q\ what would I put (Q=0, Q\=1 or viceversa)?

Comment: @LucaS it is normal to assume the startup condition is with the latch reset, that is Q low and Q/ high if there is no other information to the contrary.

Comment: I've tried doing the second diagram however it doesn't seem to come out as it is sketched I don't know if I'm messing something up.

Comment: I started at S=0 and R=0 assuming that Q=0 and Q\=1 then from there I did as you said first 10ns I put the value of Q\ and after again 10ns I put the value of Q. When I did this I went on to the next S and R state which is S=1 and R=0, I drew the diagram with the previous outputs and then saw what was the answer to this state and drew it as before

Comment: @LucaS keep trying, "When I did this I went on to the next S and R state which is S=1 and R=0"... the next SR state is both high at 40nS.. Take your time, I know it gets confusing quickly, patience is key.

Comment: At S=1 and R=0 the first time it is correct for the Q to be 1 and Q\ to be 0 but then when there is again S=1 and R=0 I would have again Q=1 and Q\=0 which is correct for Q\ but not for Q as in the solution it says that there Q has to be zero and not one. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @LucaS at what time do you see it again "S=1 and R=0"?

Comment: If you look at the second image with the other three diagrams you can see it right where the 10ns measurement is shown. First there is S and R equal to 0 then S=1 and R=0 twice and then after the second time it changes to S=1 and R=1.

Comment: @LucaS which is exactly the same as the first 40nS of your first chart for Q & Q/..... I don't see what you think is different.

Comment: You know what thank you very much for your help but it's late and I'm fed up with this argument that my professor wasn't able to teach us well and explain us fully.

Comment: @LucaS it's a tricky thing to juggle in your head. And yes you need to ne awake and alert to do it. Try again in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

As Trevor shared the image in the comment, S-R latch contains NOR gates. In the first timing diagram, when S becomes 1, after 10ns QN becomes 0, and 10ns later Q becomes 1. Now, draw the S-R latch with NOR gates, write initial values near corresponding letters (S=0, R=0, Q=0, QN=1), change S to 1, and try to understand what changes you see. If you struggle, look at the timing diagram you shared.

Comment: I did as you said I changed S to 1 which has Q becomes 1 however looking at the first timing diagram the state of Q doesn't got to 1 but stays at zero.

Comment: The diagram has been set according to delay of the NOR gate, which is the time the result of the NOR gate takes to perform. S and Q are 2 inputs of the NOR gate and the result of this gate is QN. Let say, when t=0 we change S to 1. When t=10ns, result of the NOR gate whose inputs are S and Q changes to 0. As you know QN is also input of the other NOR gate, so same delay story there too. 10 ns after QN becomes 0, the gate's output which is Q changes to 1. We have 2 gates each of which takes 10 ns to perform its task.